# EasyAdmin3: two-column concept (bootstrap) on edit form

Tags: bootstrap-4, symfony5, easyadmin

**Background**

I'm using EasyAdmin3 (Symfony 5) and I would like to have a two-column concept in the EDIT-View. The code below is "reducing" the width of a block correctly to 50%, but they are not next to each other.

```php
class PersonCrudController extends AbstractCrudController {
    [...]

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable {

        yield FormField::addPanel('Block 1')->setCssClass('col-sm-6');
        [...]

        yield FormField::addPanel('Block 2')->setCssClass('col-sm-6');
        [...]
    }

    [...]
}
```

**Question**

I quess, I need to surround it with a DIV-element containing `class="row"`. But how?

Any idea, what I can do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My workaround**

I decided to solve it with JavaScript. So I checked the HTML-Code for the name of the FORM and inject with JavaScript the `row`-class to this element. The JavaScript-file needs to be populated via the Dashboad-Controller (to be reusable for additional elements in future).

**my_javascript.js**

```js
// call functions once page is loaded
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    addClassToElement('edit-Person-form', 'row');
});

function addClassToElement(elementName, className) {
    let element = document.getElementById(elementName);

    if (element != null) {
        element.classList.add(className);
    }
}
```

**dashboard-controller**

```php
[...]
public function configureAssets(): Assets {
    $assets = parent::configureAssets();

    $assets->addJsFile('js/my_javascript.js');

    return $assets;
}
[...]
```

**PersonCrudController**

```php
class PersonCrudController extends AbstractCrudController {
    [...]

    public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable {

        yield FormField::addPanel('Block 1')->setCssClass('col-sm-6');
        [...]

        yield FormField::addPanel('Block 2')->setCssClass('col-sm-6');
        [...]
    }

    [...]
}
```